# asp.net update panel with long running process

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a long running process.

Which takes backup of MySQL server database and create an rar file.

This process takes few minutes but works fine.

My problem is when i write my code inside update panel it doesn't update form control after process completion.

### Html

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uPnlMain" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate> 
         controls goes here......

         <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Backup" />
         <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Clear" OnClick="btnClear_Click" />
    <ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

### Server Side

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //This process takes few minutes in execution.
   code goes here...
   //call update panel update method.
   uPnlMain.Update();
}
```

Can any one tell me what is the problem and how can i solve this.

Note:- Under update panel this code works fine but it doesn't update any control on form.
It takes backup and create rar as well as.

Answer (score 0):

You need a script manager to update forms in asp.net.  Try something like this bro: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx. BTW can you post the code to back up the mysql database into a rar?

Comment: Sorry i missed to mention that i already used ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager in my html markup.Check now.
And also i used update panel so many times and it works fine for small processes.

Comment: Plz check my post [How to execute backup of large database of mysql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583564/how-to-execute-backup-of-large-database-of-mysql-server). For backup code.